# Lie bracket of general unipotent matrices

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $k$ be a field (of characteristic $0$). Let
$$
X:=\begin{pmatrix}1&x_{1,2}&x_{1,3}&\cdots&x_{1,n}\\ &1&x_{2,3}&\cdots&x_{2,n}\\ &&1&\cdots&x_{3,n}\\ &&&\ddots&\vdots\\ &&&&1\end{pmatrix},\quad Y:=\begin{pmatrix}1&y_{1,2}&y_{1,3}&\cdots&y_{1,n}\\ &1&y_{2,3}&\cdots&y_{2,n}\\ &&1&\cdots&y_{3,n}\\ &&&\ddots&\vdots\\ &&&&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
be two general unipotnet matrices of size $n$. Then the Lie bracket $[X,Y]$ has the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0&0&*&\cdots&*\\ &0&0&\cdots&*\\ &&0&\cdots&*\\ &&&\ddots&\vdots\\ &&&&0\end{pmatrix},
$$
where the $0$'s are on the sub-diagonal and $*$ represents a nonzero polynomial in $x_{i,j},y_{i,j}$. For instance, when $n=3$,
$$
[X,Y]=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&x_{1,2}y_{2,3}-x_{2,3}y_{1,2}\\ &0&0\\ &&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$

In the Lie bracket $[X,Y]$, when $n<6$, all the nonzero polynomials (the stars in the above matrix) form a regular sequence in the ring $k[x_{i,j},y_{i,j}]$. For instance, when $n=3$, there is only one polynomial so it forms a trivial regular sequence. This is checked by brutal force.

However, in the case when $n=6$, the polynomials do not form a regular sequence. I do not really see any reason why this particular thing happens.

I think that this has probably been studied by other people, but after some searching, I didn't really find anything helpful. I'm wondering if anyone knows about this phenomenon could give me some reference, so that I can understand more about this happens. Thanks.

Comment: What is a regular sequence?

Comment: @Echo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_sequence

Comment: Shouldn't Lie bracket of two upper triangular matrices have zero diagonal? Anyway, does the observed result depend on the ordering of off-diagonal entries?

Comment: @AndreiSmolensky Yes the diagonals should be 0. Those are my typos and I've fixed them.
In this case, the order does not really matter. Or if you like, this could be interpreted as "when $n<6$, there is an order of polynomials that could make them a regular sequence, and when $n=6$, there is no such order."